# Parse string date/time with full time zone name in it

Tags: javascript

I would like to parse date/times in the following format:

`2019.01.21 00:47:01 CST (Asia/Shanghai)`

and not relying on the CST part, just the full time zone written at the end. I do not know the technical term for that kind of time zone but it is written by a Java program using the Java 8 Date Time API.

How could I do this? either with pure JavaScript or if JQuery can help that is ok too since I have access to it already in the page.

also if this is overly convoluted to do then I would also be open to using a 3rd party library dedicated to this kind of thing, but I would prefer not to if not necessary.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: no, just googling and the best I came across was moment (_less than ideal since it requires a library_) but I couldn't find any stack overflow questions specifically addressing this "long-format" time zone.

Comment: Have you tried the [MDN Javascript documentation?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: The `Continent/Region` name is the proper naming of a time zone. See [this list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (possibly outdated). **Never use the 2-4 letter pseudo-codes** such as `IST`, `PST`, `CST`. They are *not* standardized. They are not even unique! Ex: `CST` is Central Standard Time in the Americas, but also China Standard Time.

Comment: Educate the Java programmer providing you rdata to use only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for exchanging date-time values as text. The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating strings, so need to specify a formatting pattern. The code for transmitting current moment is simply `Instant.now().toString())` to get something like `2019-01-23T12:34:56.123456Z`. If using a `ZonedDateTime` object, extract a `Instant` to effectively adjust into UTC: `myZonedDateTime.toInstant().toString()`.

Comment: thanks Basil, yes I used this work-around yesterday.. wrote the epoch ms using instant in java and then read the epoch into a javascript Date. I would have preferred to not modify the java program, since that causes some other problems I need to deal with (beyond the scope of what we are discussing) - however, even though the answer code below works great in all examples below, for some reason when I tried to implement it in my javascript parsing it would result in the wrong time zone, labelled correctly but the time got offset a couple of hours that I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to achieve this:

```js
var date = moment("2019.01.21 00:47:01 CST (Asia/Shanghai)").format('YYYY MMM DD h:mm A');

console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Depending on your needs, you could also use plain javascript:

```js
var date = new Date('2019.01.21 00:47:01 CST (Asia/Shanghai)');

console.log(date);
```

Comment: thanks, I guess I'll have to use this library, right? I mean regular JS can't understand "Asia/Shanghai", can it?

Comment: Ah maybe I misread your question, you want to parse dates that are in that format or you want to parse them to that format?

Comment: parse them from that format to a Date variable, seems like you answering everything perfectly - thanks